# MySql - return 3 different counts

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, called users, tracklist, comments, votes.

I wanted to return the number of tracklist for each user, so I've done this query :

```
SELECT datereg, nickname, count(*) 
FROM users JOIN tracklist ON nickname=usersub
GROUP BY nickname 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, nickname ASC
```

Now, I'd like to return the number of tracklist and comments and votes. So I wrote :

```
SELECT datereg, nickname, count(*) 
FROM users JOIN tracklist ON nickname=usersub JOIN comments ON nickname=usercom JOIN votes ON nickname=uservote
GROUP BY nickname 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, nickname ASC
```

But I also would like to return 3 different count(*), 1 for tracklist, 1 for comments and 1 for votes.

Of course, if count(*) is 0, I Would like to return 0. So the value must appair in the result and must not be ignored.

How can I do this query? Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I think you may need separate queries or at least one query with separate subqueries. These are 3 different unrelated pieces of data. If they're not related, you can't express the data as a relational query...

Comment: Not sure about how to do this 3 subqueries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 3 separate subqueries

Comment: Uhm.. Thanks for the reply. But how can I do it?

Comment: Example: `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AS num1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) AS num2`

Comment: this won't work I think! In fact I need to do a sort of JOIN after a selection..or at least I think so...